# How to define a tuple type for class members generally?

Tags: c++11, tuples

For example

```
#define MEMBERS(...) using Members = decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__));

struct A
{
    int i;
    float f;
    MEMBERS(i, f); // Error
};
```

How to use a macro to define the tuple type by using members other than their types?

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/FTRX29135). How about actually stating **what** error you are seeing?

Comment: I am using VS2013. Error 1 error C2784: 'std::tuple<_Unrefwrap<_Types>::type...> std::make_tuple(_Types &&...)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Types &&' from 'unknown'.